# API request loop through pagination in python

Tags: python, api, loops

i am looking to loop through the coingecko api for all of the exchanges listed on there, pull the tickers that are listed for each exchange [this is paginated to 100 rows], loop through all of the pages. There is no way of telling how many. Then store all rows out to a CSV.

Here is what I have came up with so far.

```
from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI
cg = CoinGeckoAPI()

import pandas as pd

#grab a list of all the exchangeslisted on CG

ex_list = cg.get_exchanges_list()
#df_ex_list = pd.read_json(exchanges_list)

df = pd.json_normalize(ex_list)

#output to csv
df.to_csv('exchange_list.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)

id_list =  df['id'].tolist()


def get_ex_tickers():
    for x in id_list:
        
        # get tickers        
        d = cg.get_exchanges_tickers_by_id(x, page_integer = 2)###the num of page integers is not know
        
        #import into pandas df
        df = pd.json_normalize(d, record_path=['tickers'], meta=['name'])    
        
        #define path + filename        
        path = 'ticker_lists/'        
        filename = path+ x +'_ticker_list' + '.csv'
        
        #output to csv
        df.to_csv(filename, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
    
        
get_ex_tickers()
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: I dont know how to loop through the number of pages

Comment: I dont know what 'pages' are. Is it part of CoinGeckoAPI? Look at the API docs.

Comment: pagers_integer is part of the api. For the request there will be multiple pages and the API is set to only give the first page_integer. So I need to find out how to loop though page_integer N=1 until we get to the last page

Comment: if each request returns a max of 100 pieces of data, cant you loop from the first page until you get one return with 99 or less pieces?

Comment: @Technaut hey, were you able to figure it out?

Comment: nope never solved it :/